# How do I correct value in a data-frame that came with package (zipcode) and make it stick?

Tags: r

I was trying to filter a data table by zip codes in NYC. And using:

```
library(zipcode)
data("zipcode")
```

to cross-reference, during which I discovered that zip 10004 was incorrectly listed as "NJ". I stumbled on this error only because 10004 is adjacent to mine; so naturally my fake zip on random websites and my goto zip for testing. Hopefully there are not other zips similarly mis-"stated". But... a problem for another day.

Doing `zipcode[3899, 3] = "NY"` fixes it for the session but I would like to know how to change it in the dataset embedded in the package itself (on my machine).

Comment: I would reach out to package authors. Maybe they can fix quickly with a development and later CRAN version.

Answer (score 1):

Per the R Documentation for the [zipcodes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zipcode/zipcode.pdf) package, this package has been orphaned as of June 16, 2014.

The underlying data is located at [freezipcodes.us](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/) and has not been updated since January 2012.

Therefore, you're better off finding another source of zipcode data.

Comment: Yes, I saw that;  also many of the top hits have similar errors; another site locates this ZIP entirely on Governor's Island and has 10005 over Bowling Green.  So I'm sticking with my self-corrected version of this data for now.